# How to print the JSON object in Android using a try block

Tags: android, mysql, json

I need to get the JSON object from MySQL database, and to print it as string. Also, I need to pass that string to a `try` block to open required class activity. Here, I have attached my code below, check my code and let me know.

My JSON object sample:

```
{ "id": "381", "task": "user_confirm", "message": "New booking details" }
```

My Android Code:

```
public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login_Activity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.main_logo);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bike_start);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(path);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
            Log.e("JsonOutput", json.toString());
            sendNotification(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    //        sendNotification1(String.valueOf(remoteMessage), image);
    // Log.e("body", body);
}

private void sendNotification(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Notifications JSON1 " + json.toString());

    try {
         JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
         Log.d("data", String.valueOf(data));
         //parsing json data
         id = data.get("id").toString();
         message = data.get("message").toString();
         task = data.get("task").toString();
         Log.d("Id values", id);
         Log.d("Message", message);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Notifications JSON1 `{"id":"381","task":"user_confirm","message":"New booking details"}`

Comment: There is no relation for `php` tag and `mysql` tag... Change to add `json` tag

Answer (score 1):

As per your attached `JSON` response, there is no `JSONObject` named `"data"` in your `JSON` data.

**Parse JSON data as below:**

```
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        Log.e("JsonOutput", json.toString());
        sendNotification(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
...........
.......................

private void sendNotification(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Notifications JSON1 " + json.toString());

    try {
         // Parsing id, task and message from json JSONObject 
         String id = json.getString("id");
         String task = json.getString("task");
         String message = json.getString("message");

         Log.d("Id: ", id);
         Log.d("Task: ", task);
         Log.d("Message: ", message);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Hope this will work~

Comment: Check my updated answer. use `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());` instead of `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());`

Answer (score 0):

Use like this for FCM:

```
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        String message=remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
}
```

Comment: private void sendNotification(JSONObject json) {
             Log.e(TAG, "Notifications JSON1 " + json.toString());

          try {
         
         
         id = json.getString("id");
         message = json.getString("message");
   task = json.getString("task");
         
         Log.d("Id values", id);
   Log.d("Message", message);
         Log.d("task", task);
    }